# My homemade variable power supply burns potentiometer

Tags: power-supply, pcb

I have designed my Power supply using this schematic [image]
And this is my pcb[image]
[image]
Everything is connected right but the potintemeter burned twice

Onething i am suspicious of are the parts 
C1 1000uf 35v, 
C2 0.1uf, 
C3 470uf 35v,
C4 10uf 35v but unfortunately I couldn't find it 35v so i bought 10uf 50v which i think is the problem

Is the Pcb okay and if so what is the problem causing the potentiometer to burn ?

Comment: 1 - Have you tried replacing RV1 with a fixed 1k resistor and checking out the voltage levels? 2 - With all due respect that's a lousy layout. Most importantly, you have no easy way to add a heat sink to your LM317, and (trust me) at low voltages it will need it. For instance, at 5 volts out and 1 amp, your 317 will need to dissipate on the order of 15 to 20 watts, and without a very substantial heat sink it will go into thermal limit in a matter of seconds. Worry more about functionality and less about pretty. 3 - 10 uF @ 50 volts is fine.

Comment: I added one more pic showing the pcb and the lm317, the readings are when there is nothing connected between the pins for the fixed potentiometer arms i got 35v when placing fixed 10k i got 34.6v and 32v for 1k

Comment: The 1k ohm resistor is 0.25 watt and got over heated very fast

Comment: Right. So you need to learn to work fast. Make a test connection with the power off, turn on the power, read the voltage, then turn off the power. Now record the voltage you read on the proper point of the schematic. After a few cycles you'll have mapped out the circuit and can try to figure out what has gone wrong. Oh yeah, and that heat sink is not adequate if you're trying for 2 amps out.

Comment: One more thing the output current is always zero no Matter what's connected instead of the potentiometer, it should be 1A maximum

Comment: You ask whether the PCB is okay but only show the component side. If there are errors on the solder side people can't help you spot them.

Comment: Of course the current out is zero. You have no load connected.

Comment: Try the next: without the pot connected power on your power supply and check the output voltage, if it's 37V then short your pins 1-2 or 1-3 of your pot BRIEFLY and check the output, if it gives you 1.25v you're in the right way, otherwise there's a problem with you pcb or the schematic, if it shows 1.25v then put you multimeter in 10A and short pins 1-2 or 1-3 across the multimeter and check the current flowing through and post the results.

Comment: It gives 36v when there is nothing connected and 26v when shorting pins 1-2

Comment: Stating you measured the output current and it's zero I may guess you tried to read the output current in short circuit, if it says zero then you probably have blown your IC, always measure the output current with a load

Comment: Have you got one of the diodes the wrong way round?

Comment: There is something odd with the PCB layout. D1 and D2 on the PCB are named D3 and D4 on the circuit. A burning ADJ pot is what I would expect by connection the LM317 in a mirror position.

Comment: There are 2 possible sources of your high current, the regulator and D5. Remove the LM317. (while you do this, check to make sure you did not accidentally short the input and output pins by sloppy soldering). Apply power, and the output should be zero (or very close - certainly less than 0.1 volt). If not, either D5 is shorted or installed backwards. If D5 is good, remove VR1, and replace R2 with a 1k. Install a new LM317, and apply power. Output should be about 6.9 volts, and the ADJ voltage about 5.7.

Comment: Is it just me is is R1 missing on that board? It would explain the full output voltage but not the burning pot, and yea I would second the comment about 'interesting' layout decisions. A shorted R1 or D6 would burn the pot (Or a shorted LM317 obviously).

Comment: R1 is placed under the heatsink

Comment: Make completely sure the heatsink (Which is totally inadequate by the way) is not shorting to the end of R1 connected to pin 1 on the LM317, that would do it.

Comment: Plz share a picture of the solder side of the pcb. Or verify the solder side closely as already advised. 3 most possible cases are- D6 damaged or reversed, LM317 is burnt, or output pin 1 or 2 touched the line passing in between due to bad soldering.

Comment: and another thing. Please measure your transformer AC voltage. The schematic you provided shows a 21 volt unit, and there is no way you are doing that. You obviously have a higher transformer voltage

Answer (score 1):

If shorting pins 1-2 from the pot give you an output higher than 1.25v then there I see a couple of possibilities.

1) The diode coming across output and input pin of Lm317 is damaged or placed in the wrong direction, check if removing it solves the problem (working without this diode won't damage your circuit unless you apply inductive loads at the output).

2) The IC may have burned and there is no regulation of 1.25v, check the voltage across your 220ohm resistor, it should always be 1.25v.

3) If none of the above solves the problem try arranging the circuit in a protoboard, if it works OK then you might have a broken trace or shortened traces in your pcb.

Comment: I desoldered D5 and D6 but nothing happend, i used the Lm in a separate circuit supplied by a 9 v battary with a 5k potentiometer it gives output voltage between 8v and 5.7v it never drops to 1.25v even when i shorted the  adjustment pin and connect it to ground

Comment: Then your LM317 is not regulating it's output, it should always regulate the voltage between output and adj pin with 1.25v across a 220ohm resistor. Try using another LM317.

Answer (score -1):

No, using higher rated caps is not a problem.  What is the power rating of your potentiometer?  Do you have a part number or datasheet?  Most likely the circuit is passing too much current through it.  Does it burn when turned all the way to one side only?

The layout appears to match the schematic (although you have some components labeled differently like the diodes which was confusing).

Comment: Answers shouldn't be asking the OP for clarification. This should be a comment.

Comment: The potentiometer is WL B10k, it start burning once power is supplied and the output voltage is always 36v.

Comment: "No, using higher rated caps is not a problem." was my first answer.

Comment: @MahmoudMansour I found various places selling that part, but no datasheets yet, and none seem to specify the power rating.  Do you have any more information on it?  It looks fairly large though so I would think it could handle this application.  Perhaps you could measure the current through the pot with the wiper in different positions.

Comment: Once I connect anther one it will burn sir, so how can i measure the current ?

Comment: @MahmoudMansour - Per my comment - replace the pot with a fixed resistor. If a 1/4 watt burns up, you can try a 1 watt.